# Unset custom data from product attribute

Tags: magento2, product, custom, custom-attributes

I am trying to update a product with some **custom attributes**. I need to unset data that is being passed to set the value to none. I am currently on Magento 2.1

```
... 
 $updatedProduct->unsetData($customAttributeA);
 $updatedProduct->save();
```

I added a break-point after unset the data, **customAttributeA** row is indeed gone from the product data array. However, after calling the save function, customAttributeA comes back into the array, with the value previously set.

Is there a way to persist the unsetData during the save function? I have also tried

```
$product->setData($customAttributeA , "");
And
$product->setCustomAttribute($customAttributeA , "");
```

However, none of them seems to work.

> The attribute type i am trying to unset is a dropdown type.

Cheers

> edit- this is a snapshot of the code i am using to set/unset the data

```
 foreach ($listTypes as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($params[$value])){
       if(isset($params[$value . '_mid'])) {
           $product->setCustomAttribute($value, $params[$value.'_mid']);
       }else{     
           // unset data here
       }
    }
 }

 $product->save();
```

Comment: Any ideas anyone? I'm wasting a lot of time trying various methods but nothing seems to work.

Comment: just to update, whoever comes across this issue in the future. I've given up doing this via the product model, i am directly querying the database tables to remove the option-value row directly.

Answer (score 3):

I found this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/8672847. It looks like Magento 1 code but it's work for me.

```
$product->setData('unwanted_attribute',null);        
$resource = $product->getResource();
$resource->saveAttribute($product,'unwanted_attribute');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try with below for unset data,

**1st way**

> You have to use setData() instead of unsetData() for unset data.

```
$updatedProduct->setData($customAttributeA);
$updatedProduct->save();
```

**2nd Way,**

```
unset($customAttributeA);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rakesh. i tried the 1st way, it does have the same behavior as the methods i used previously. It sets the attribute value to null, however, it doesn't persist through the save method. And the second method, doesn't seem to affect anything though ( I used $updatedProduct->unset($customAttributeA);

Comment: I just understood your 2nd method, i'll try it again soon

Comment: Is it useful in your case?

Comment: I just tried, nope, method 2 does not work as well unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to unset a custom attribute on a product, so I removed the record from the database instead. Below is the code if anyone is interested.

```
private function unsetCustomAttribute($magentoProduct, $attributeCode)
{
    $this->logger->debug("Unset custom attribute '" . $attributeCode . "' on product '" . $magentoProduct->sku . "'");

    /** @var ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository */
    $attributeRepository = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface::class);
    $attribute = $attributeRepository->get($attributeCode);

    /** @var ResourceConnection $resources */
    $resources = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ResourceConnection::class);

    /** @var AdapterInterface $connection */
    $connection = $resources->getConnection();
    $connection->delete("catalog_product_entity_int", "entity_id = " . $magentoProduct->id . " AND attribute_id = " . $attribute->getAttributeId());
}
```